# What is the difference between these statements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

what is the difference between below a and b statements in jQuery.

**a**

```
$('#mytable').find('tr td:eq(0)').each(function(){});
```

**b**

```
$('#mytable').find('tr').find('td:eq(0)').each(function(){});
```

Comment: I think Both are same but i would recommend first one because it will not lookup for the second time

Comment: They are the damn same.

Comment: I agree. Both are the same. The only difference is how you locate the target elements. You can be as specific or careless with find() as you want.

Comment: all above comments are same but wrong!

Comment: `.each()` is not needed at all. Also I really cannot believe you could not  create a TABLE and test.

Answer (score 4):

Statement a will return the first `td` in the table `#mytable`, where as the statement `b` will return all the first `td` elements of all `tr`s in table `#mytable`.

So in abstract `a` will return 0 or 1 `td`, where as `b` could return `n` number of `td` elements

```js
$('#mytable').find('tr td:eq(0)').css('color', 'red'); 

$('#mytable').find('tr').find('td:eq(0)').css('background-color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>1.1</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>1.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2.1</td>
        <td>2.2</td>
        <td>2.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3.1</td>
        <td>3.2</td>
        <td>3.3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle. I am really confused at this point of time after reading your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Because :eq() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :eq() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use $("your-pure-css-selector").eq(index) instead.

Refered this [link](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Comment: Not that performance matters but the two examples the OP provided match completely different elements. (Also I cannot believe OP did not created a simple demo to test for it self...)

Comment: Posted the answer to let OP know that one of the difference is performance.